# Have certain static cells fill rest of view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a `TableViewController` with **6 static cells**. Is it possible to have the top **2 cells a certain height**, then the **bottom 4 fill up the remaining area** of the screen? If the user has a larger phone, it will take up the rest of the area like normal, if a user has a small phone, the cell height will resize small enough so that there is no scrolling needed.

Comment: Since a `UITableView` is designed with scrolling in mind, if you have only *"6 static cells"* this might be much easier to implement with a `UIStackView` than with a tableview.

Comment: Hmm that is a good point, why am I trying to do this through cells instead of a stack view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.row {
        case 0, 1:
            return x // first 2 cell height
        default:
            return (tableView.frame.height - (2 * x)) / 4 // rest of the cells
    }
}
```

Replace **x** with your desired height for the first 2 cells

Explication:

The height for the rest of the cells is calculated based on tableView height, substracting the first 2 cells height and diveded by 4 for 4 cells